# How to scrape or grab a photo from mediaElement

Tags: windows-phone-7

I try the code below to **scrape** a photo from a running video or stop from MediaElement.
There is no error but no photo show and no photo being scraped and saved in Photo Hub. What seems to be the problem? Would appreciate your help.

```
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(mediaElement1,null);
    
        wb.Invalidate();    
        wb.Render(mediaElement1, new TranslateTransform());
      
        MemoryStream msWrite = new MemoryStream();

        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, msWrite, 640, 480, 0, 100);

    
        msWrite.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    
        MediaLibrary ML = new MediaLibrary();
        ML.SavePicture("test" + ".jpg", msWrite);


        //-- Display the capture image from mediaElement

        image1.Source = wb;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue. The WebBrowser control doesn't work either.

> WriteableBitmap currently does not capture the content of WebBrowser
>   control or MediaElement.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/a9000cc6-7b3b-4226-a769-5217707c7165/screenshot)

Comment: Thanks. read that link. is it going to be implemented with the capture capability or it will never be implemented? any work around?

Comment: I don't know about the future SDK and I'm afraid there is no workaround at the moment.